Run script and update same cell when changes to spreadsheet are made
I'm trying to update the cell when changes are made on any sheet in the workbook. Here is the script that only runs when I initially call the function in the cell
function countColoredCells(countRange, colorRef) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  let searchColor, countRangeA1;
  try {
    const colorRefA1 = formula.match(/\,(.+)\)/).pop().trim();
    searchColor = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(colorRefA1).getBackground();
    countRangeA1 = formula.match(/\((.+)\,/).pop().trim();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Bad arguments.');
  }
  let count = 0;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    count += sheet.getRange(countRangeA1).getBackgrounds()
      .flat()
      .filter(c => c === searchColor)
      .length
  });
  return count;
}

Here is what I'm calling in the cell
=countColoredCells(A:A,'Practice Sheet'!A6)

After I change something in the spreadsheet and manually run the script I keep getting the Error Bad arguments
I tried to add a trigger to run the script upon changes in the spreadsheet. I keep getting the bad arguments error and the cell is not updating the new number

You get "Error Bad Arguments" on which line?  Don't make us guess.

@TimRoberts Line 10 sorry

Your try/catch are hiding the actual error.  Remove them, and just let the actual error happen.

"manually run the script" — if you run a custom function directly in the script editor, no arguments get passed. The correct behavior is to error out. Without the try...catch the error is Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pop'). The Bad argument error is easier to interpret. The question fails to attribute the code to this answer. @TimRoberts

This is essentially the same question as Update cells with custom formula upon any part of workbook being edited. The OP has posted the same at least three times now.

This question is similar to: App Script: How to update spreadsheet cell with live data. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
